# Angular 2+ use Alertifyjs ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: angular

```
declare var alertify:any;
export class ExamplComponent implements OnInit {
    itemList = []

    deleteItem(idx) {
    alertify.confirm('Are you sure delete this record.', function() {
      this.itemList.slice(idx,1);
    })
  }
}
```

> html Page

```
< div *ngFor="let item of itemList;let indx = index" style="text-align: center">
    <button class="text-btn text-danger" (click)="deleteItem(indx)" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</div>
```

> Source Library: https://alertifyjs.com/confirm.html
>
> Error Message

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemList' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

use `fat arrow =>` instead of `function`

```
deleteItem(idx) {
    alertify.confirm('Are you sure delete this record.', ()=> {
      this.itemList.slice(idx,1);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the function passed as argument to `alertify.confirm()`. In this case when you declare a function using `function()` it has its own `this`; therefore, when you code `this.itemList` you are pointing to `undefined` as it doesn't exist on your function.

Try to use arrow function instead (`() => {}`), they inherit the `this` from the current scope, so it is safe to use within a callback.

```
deleteItem(idx) {
    alertify.confirm('Are you sure delete this record.', () => {
      this.itemList.slice(idx, 1)
    })
}
```